# What is the side effect when hyperref has stopped early?

Tags: beamer, hyperref, captions

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Are you kidding?}
No! I am not a good joker.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The following is taken from Ulrike's comment:

> beamer loads hyperref with the option
>   `implicit=false`. This option inserts a
>   `\endinput` in the command
>   `\MaybeStopEarly` in hyperref and has
>   the effect that about 2000 lines of
>   code of hyperref are not executed.
>   This 2000 lines contains a lot of
>   definitions and redefinitions. One of
>   them is e.g. that it inserts in
>   `\@caption` the command
>   `\hyper@makecurrent{\@captype}`. So
>   getting rid of the warning by giving
>   `\hyper@makecurrent` and empty
>   definition **will quite probably not
>   enable hyperref support**.

The next question becomes:
Why does beamer load incompletely hyperref? What is the purpose?

Comment: @xport I am not kidding remove `\usepackage{caption}`:).

Comment: @xport: There's no need to use captions in a presentation.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, but it is very special case, I have to present how to use LaTeX to the audience. The presentation must contain `LTXexample` environment with many other LaTeX environments inside. One of the topics is about caption.

Comment: @xport: Import your example as a PDF file

Comment: @xport use `\documentclass[final]{beamer}` and it should fix it, seriously:)

Comment: @egreg: If I convert the example to PDF and import it from within the beamer main input file, LTXexample will be useless.

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the `caption` package documentation, these are the lines which are responsible for the warning:

```
\caption@IfPackageLoaded{hyperref}[2003/11/30 v6.74m]{%
 \@ifundefined{hyper@makecurrent}{% hyperref has stopped early
 \caption@WarningNoLine{%
 Hyperref support is turned off\MessageBreak
 because hyperref has stopped early}%
 }{%
```

Thus, the warning is produced because the `hyperref` package is not loaded completely when using the `beamer` document class.

So if you *really* need to use the `caption` package and want to get rid of the warning, you could add the following lines

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\hyper@makecurrent[1]{}
\makeatother
```

*before* loading the `caption` package.

Comment: @xport:  the warning produced by loading `caption` indicates that caption turns off its hyperef support; on the other side, `hyperref` is not loaded completely and it emits the message `Hyperref stopped early` (you can see it in the .log file) independently of loading or not `caption`. The message issued by hyperref is a simple `\typeout`, not a warning, so I think there's not any negative effects added.

Comment: `beamer` loads hyperref with the option `implicit=false`. This option inserts a `\endinput` in the command `\MaybeStopEarly` in hyperref and has the effect that about 2000 lines of code of `hyperref` are not executed. This 2000 lines contains a lot of definitions and redefinitions. One of them is e.g. that it inserts in `\@caption` the command `\hyper@makecurrent{\@captype}`. So getting rid of the warning by giving \hyper@makecurrent and empty definition will quite probably not enable `hyperref` support.

Comment: Beside this: `\hyper@makecurrent` is used in the false branch of the test in `caption`. So if you really want to lie to `caption` you should at least give it the right number of arguments `\newcommand\hyper@makecurrent[1]{}`

Comment: I cancel the green mark because you are not sure whether or not this issue has negative effects.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of "help" that makes package authors scream - because if then somehow caption breaks and you contact the author of caption, you are out of luck. 

Beamer + hyperref + caption doesn't work. Get used to it.