# Beamer: understanding hyperref messages "stopped early" and "Driver (autodected): hpdftex"

Tags: beamer, hyperref

EDIT: The second message ("Driver (autodected): hpdftex") has been explained.

OS X, TexLive 2011 (basic) installed through MacTeX. I update everything with `tlmgr` daily. This minimal beamer example produces the below messages with `pdflatex` but not `latex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{
  Heteronormativity.
}
\end{document}
```

Messages:

```
Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

)

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
```

I do not get any other errors or warnings (e.g. related to `pgf`, `\thepage`, etc.)

Comment: The second message just means `hyperref` has detected that you are using `pdflatex`. I think there is more than one way to cause the first. Is there an actual problem, though?

Comment: As stated, no: I get good output, no errors, no warnings. This is a curiosity question. Coincidentally, thank you for explaining the second message.

Comment: This is just information. You could use the `silence` package to try to remove them, but what is the issue here? There is a general feeling that LaTeX packages should be quite verbose (_i.e._ that the log is meant to be a record of everything important that happens).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21104/what-is-the-side-effect-when-hyperref-has-stopped-early

Comment: @Dan --- Maybe you should edit the question title; 'getting rid of hyperref messages' makes it appear that you need to eliminate them.

Comment: As explained in the thread I mentioned, there's no support for "beamer+caption" (the latter package is causing the message). On the other hand, captions in beamer presentations are not that useful, are they?

Comment: I am not using the caption package. I've updated the question to be clear. I read your thread before posting, of course. :)

Comment: @Dan You're right. I guess that until Heiko Oberdiek fixes it, there's little to do.

Answer (score 15):

The message

```
Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.
```

is annoying, but seems to be innocuous. There's nothing that can be done until `hyperref` is modified to take care of it.

Comment: It is still there

Comment: All the same, today.

Comment: And two years later, as well.